# Why can't I use the className attribute for some React.Components?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

The CSS style class works here:

```
<span className="cake">Cake</span>
```

However, this fails (well, no style changes picked up in browser):

```
<Nav.Link href="/xyz" className="cake">Cake</Nav.Link>
```

Why does the className atrtibute only work sometimes?

How should you add custom style to `<Nav.Link>`s, for example right justify only the Logoff one?

Comment: By "failing", what exactly do you mean? The style associated with that class doesn't get applied right?

Comment: Yes, will edit to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether that style is picked up by the browser or not depends on how `Nav.Link` is defined.

For example, if it's defined like this (using `styled-components`):

```
const NavLink = styled.div`
  /* some styles */
`;
```

it will work, because all props are passed to `div`.

However, if it's defined like this:

```
const NavLink = ({ href, children }) => {
  return <a href={href}>children</a>;
};
```

it will swallow `className`.

Generally, a good practice is passing all extra props up the hierarchy like this:

```
const NavLink = ({ href, children, ...rest }) => {
  return <a href={href} {...rest}>children</a>;
};
```

But we never know how it's defined. (You'd better check the definition in `node_modules`.)

Comment: Thanks. Assuming it's the second way, and I'm not supposed to be patching the `react-bootstrap` module, how might most people probably apply styles to individual `Nav.Link`s?

Comment: You can update the class name with `bsPrefix` and then apply the style to that class: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props

Comment: I'm not sure we're in the right place here. The docs say "This is an escape hatch for working with heavily customized bootstrap css."  This seems off the beaten path to me. I'm also failing to get multiple class assignment to render `<Nav.Link href="/cake" bsPrefix="nav-link cake">`.  The rendering in browser only reflect membership of class `nav-link`.